# Program VB.Net for use on Windows-2000

Tags: vb.net, windows-2000

Newbie question - How do I set up a VB.NET program so it will run on W2K ?  I understand I can only use .Net 2.0 or older.  Is there an easy way to limit which .net version is used/referenced ?  (I have .Net 3.5 on my XP development computer) Updating target computers to XP, Vista, Windows 7 is NOT an option.

Answer (score 1):

Have your Visual Studio VB.NET project target the .NET Framework runtime version you install on your 2000 workstation.

With Visual Studio 2008 you can choose to target .NET 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5.

There are (at least) two ways to do this for a VB.NET project:

First, when you create a project.  On the New Project dialog, there's a drop down on the top right-hand side of the screen from which you can specify the project's target Framework version.

Second, you can change the version by right clicking the project and selecting Properties.  Click the Compile tab on the left and then click the 'Advanced Compile Options...' button.  The 'Advanced Compiler Options' dialog appears and you can select the framework version on the pulldown on the bottom of the dialog. (it's certainly much easier to do this in a C# project!)

Comment: Express Edition does not allow to change the target version...in that case he'd have to use an alternate IDE like SharpDevelop (or edit it by hand, but I'm not sure if that will work).